# SimpleDateFormat 24h

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I've got a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse a `String` into a `Date`:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
```

When I'm parsing this:

```
format.parse("2011-08-29T12:44:00+0200");
```

The result will be, when using `Date.toLocaleString`:

> 29 aug. 2011 00:44:00

This should be ofcourse:

> 29 aug. 2011 12:44:00

And when I'm parsing this:

```
format.parse("2011-08-29T13:44:00+0200");
```

Then the result is as expected:

> 29 aug. 2011 13:44:00

How can I fix this?

Comment: For new readers to this question I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 117, accepted):

[Use `HH` instead of `hh` for the hours pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Real fun when you've spent half an hour looking for a solution and it's this. (:

Comment: It's in the Javadoc for SimpleDateFormat ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### java.time through desugaring

I suggest that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

Your string is in ISO 8601 format. Define a formatter for it:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_FORMATTER
        = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                .appendOffset("+HHMM", "Z")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
```

It could have been shorter with a format pattern string, but I prefer to reuse the built-in `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`, which already handles ISO 8601. As your question testifies, writing a format pattern string is error-prone. I have also specified that an offset of zero from UTC should be accepted as `Z` in accordance with ISO 8601 (the parser will accept `+0000` too).

Parse like this:

```
    String isoString = "2011-08-29T12:44:00+0200";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(isoString, ISO_FORMATTER);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output is:

> 2011-08-29T12:44+02:00

To obtain a string formatted for the user’s locale use a second formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter LOCALE_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
```

We still need not write any format pattern string. Format like this:

```
    String localeString = dateTime.format(LOCALE_FORMATTER);
    System.out.println(localeString);
```

Output is exactly what it should be. I ran in `nl_NL` locale and got:

> 29 aug. 2011 12:44:00

Please skip the next section.

### What if I need an old-fashioned `java.util.Date`?

No one should use the `Date` class anymore. Only if you indispensably need a `Date` for a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time right now, convert:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(dateTime.toInstant());
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

Funnily output will be time zone dependent. In my time zone I got:

> Mon Aug 29 12:44:00 CEST 2011

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.