# How can i change the 12 hrs to 24 hrs date format in java?

Tags: java

I have a `String` `"2014-11-04 10:30 PM"`, but I want to display as `"2014-11-04 22:30`. How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In `Java` SimpleDateFormat you can use `hh` for `12` hours representation and `HH` for `24` hour representation.

Eg:

```
  String str="2014-11-04 10:30 PM";
  DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
  Date date=df.parse(str);
  df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
  System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Out put:

```
2014-11-04 22:30
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is here. [SimpleDateFormat 24h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229603/simpledateformat-24h)

Use HH instead of hh with SimpleDateFormat class.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

When using **Java 8** you can make use of the new [Time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

- [java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
- [java.time.LocalDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

---

```
final String input = "2014-11-04 10:30 PM";
final DateTimeFormatter inFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
final DateTimeFormatter outFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
final LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse(input, inFormatter);

System.out.println(outFormatter.format(time));
```

Output:

```
2014-11-04 22:30
```