# I got can not resolve symbol error in my networking course code

Tags: java, multithreading

I got Cannot resolve symbol 'dis_tunnel1' this error in following code. This code is for implementing of socket programming using threading. In this socket programming server can send two thing date and time to client. If client type Date then server sent Date to client and also if client type Time then server sent Time as like date.
But In my programming Cannot resolve symbol 'dis_tunnel1' this error

```
public class ClientHandler extends Thread {
    DateFormat fordate = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");
    DateFormat fortime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    final Socket com_tunnel1;
    final DataInputStream dis_tunnel1;
    final DataOutputStream dos_tunnel1;
    String received = "";
    String toreturn = "";


    public ClientHandler(Socket s, DataInputStream dis, DataOutputStream dos) {
        this.com_tunnel1 = s;
        this.dis_tunnel1 = dis;
        this.dos_tunnel1 = dos;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                dos_tunnel1.writeUTF("What do you want [Date/Time");
                received.dis_tunnel1.read_UTF();
                if (received.equals("Exit")) {
                    System.out.println("Client " + this.com_tunnel1 + " send exits..");
                    System.out.println("Closing the connections");
                    this.com_tunnel1.close();
                    break;
                }

                Date date = new Date();
                switch (received) {
                    case "Date":
                        toreturn = fordate.format(date);
                        dos_tunnel1.writeUTF(toreturn);
                        break;

                    case "Time":
                        toreturn = fortime.format(date);
                        dos_tunnel1.writeUTF(toreturn);
                        break;

                    default:
                        dos_tunnel1.writeUTF("Invalid input");
                        break;

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }
        }

        try {
            this.dos_tunnel1.close();
            this.dis_tunnel1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message? In the method `run()` you are accessing `received.dis_tunnel1`. What is that supposed to be? `received` is a String and doesn't have a property called `dis_tunnel1`.

Comment: Not answering your question, I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Also beware of the case of format pattern letters. See [Add colon to 24
hour time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862558/add-colon-to-24-hour-time-in-java) and [SimpleDateFormat 24h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229603/simpledateformat-24h).